# How can I dump a single Redis DB index?

Tags: redis

Redis SAVE and BGSAVE commands dump the complete Redis data to a persistent file.
But is there a way to dump only one DB index?

I am using the same Redis server with multiple DB indices.
I use DB 0 as config which is edited manually and contains just a small number of keys. I wish to dump this to a file as a config snapshot (versioned) to keep track of manual changes in the prod environment.
The rest of the DBs have a large number of items, that will take too long to dump, and I don't need to back them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis' persistence scope is the entire instance, meaning all shared/numbered databases and all keys in them. Saving only a subset of these is not supported.

Instead, use two independent Redis instances and configure each to persist (or not) per your needs. The overhead of running an insurance is a few megabytes so it is practically negligible.